# Power set of a set

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am new to algorithms and found this question on net:
Given a sequence of N  numbers S1, ..., SN (-20,000,000 ≤ Si ≤ 20,000,000), determine how many subsets of S (including the empty one) have a sum between A and B (-500,000,000 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 500,000,000), inclusive.

```
For  EXAMPLE:
Sequence : 1 -2 3
A= -2
B=3
The following 5 subsets have a sum between -1 and 2:

0 = 0 (the empty subset)
1 = 1
1 + (-2) = -1
-2 + 3 = 1
1 + (-2) + 3 = 2
```

My approach:

Taking All the possiable combination i.e. `j=2^n` and checking the sum
Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
    for(int k=0;k<A.length;k++){

        int temp= 1<<k;
        if( (i&temp) !=0){
            sum+=A[k];
        }
    }
    if(a<=sum &&  sum<=b){
        ans++;
        sum=0;
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

**CONS:**
What if the value of n>27 , this solution will not give me an answers till my retirement days and i want to go to movie interstellar and it's going to awesome 
Could anybody could suggest me a good algo or approach to solve this.

According to me i should sort the array and divide the array according to A and B

Comment: Homework detected. Didn't pay attention at the class?

Comment: this not a howework question and i have solved the question but when a larger value of N came it fails !!! i am just want some advice and direction i did not ask for code !!!! I want only a good approach

Comment: @Skizz a little more help !!! would you explain it a bit

Comment: Why didn't you say it only fails on big numbers? Try longer integers.

Comment: @AdrianMay let N=30 and 2^30 !!!! that's a lot big money !!!!! not possible for a simple `for` loop

Comment: So use long int or long long int instead of int.

Comment: I was thinking about some movie so I didn't understand that you were already telling us that the problem is with the speed

Comment: @AdrianMay just run simple  for loop from 0 to 10^9 in a program !!!! wait if you can come back here before 22 century

Comment: @AdrianMay now you understand the main villan of our film now it's a time to start some action !!!!

Comment: This is a generalized version of the subset sum problem, so it's NP-hard in the general case. In this case, because the values are bounded, you can use a [pseudo-polynomial time algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution), but it's still likely to take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to expand my comment above....

You can break this down in the following way:-

```
for a set S and range AB
  for each element in S
    remove element from S, call new set S'
    calculate new range A'B', where A' and B' are altered according to the removed element
    call this function using S' and A'B'
```

If the size of S is only one then:-

```
is element of S within range AB?
```

I don't know if this is the most efficent solution, but it would be my initial solution without further research. There may be a quicker way but this feels very NP to me.

The recursion is in the line 'call this function' and a google on 'recursion' will provide a lot more details on the technique.

Comment: thats!! a very kind of you !!!! now let me direct this script and get back to you if this will be hit or not

Comment: is this a really NP hard problem for n>27

Comment: I've just noticed you can have sub sets, in which case, a check for A and B being either side of zero before the main loop should solve that (if they are, then the removed elements form a set)

Comment: @user4116864: It's NP for all sets. It might not be NP. It just feels like you have to check all subsets to know for sure.

Comment: NP hard for `n>27`? Its only NP hard if `n` is variable, its easy for every constant, e.g. `n=28`. Looks pretty similar to the Knapsack Problem.

Comment: Nit: I think line 2 should say "for each element s in S with s<=B". It's not enough to only test that when the set is singular.

Comment: This is more efficient than the original idea cos it cuts out the most extreme valued of the 2^N combinations, but then it gets worse cos you re-examine the same combinations in all of their permutations. E.g., "just the first, second and third provided numbers" is one option in the naive algorithm, but now it's 6! So this might even be slower than before.

Comment: @AdrianMay: I'd have to disagree with you on your first comment. s<=B doesn't work as 'Si + Sj' could be <= B. I don't see how a none singular test would cover all possibilities. The only valid short cut I can think of is where 'A * B' is negative or zero, then the empty set is a solution. You still need to test the elements of S incase 'Si + Sj' is a valid solution as well. Your second comment about permutations is valid though, but a check at the start would eliminate the duplication (has S been done before) and is an optimisation that could be added once the algorithm has been shown to work

Comment: Oh silly me, I didn't notice the negatives in the options list. But in that case aren't you gonna wind up examining all 2^N combinations?

Comment: @AdrianMay: If all subsets are unique and there's no duplicate sub set testing then, yes, you're going to test all combinations. I'm not a maths expert but I can't see anyway to shortcut this. I've tried to say this in my answer. If there is a way then go ahead and edit this answer.

Comment: Well there's also my answer below. It might be buggy, but if not then I think it's optimal.

Answer (score 0):

We'll find the solutions with 1 element first, then those with 2, 3, ... Call that M

First sort the set.

For any M, we can recursively generate the combinations in order of gravity to the left, e.g.:

XX...

X.X..

.XX..

X..X.

.X.X.

..XX.

etc.

Let me just assume that for any member of this sequence we know how to make the next one or the previous one, and that for any M.

Now I think this list is in order of total value, so you know when to cut it off at A and B. For M=1 you'll just cruise through to A, start outputting solutions, and stop when B is exceeded, but you'll also note the index where you exceed A-S[0], S[0] being the smallest number in the set.

Now you start your M=2 run with a set consisting of the solution that just exceeded A-S[0] with S[0] thrown in. This is the smallest solution with M=2. So cruise along until you exceed B.

Now the starting point for M=3 is not so simple. The candidates have a low value of tot+x where x is a provided number but not already in the set. You can search the M=2 set in order and stop when tot-A exceeds the x of a solution already found.

That works for all subsequent values of M.

But I'm not sure if that sequence really is in order of value, and I'm not sure how to write the algorithm that gives the next combination in the sequence. Or am I? How about this:

For any combination, to make the next one in sequence, find all downgoing edges, e.g. in XX.X. we have downgoing edges after the second and fourth Xs. For each edge, calculate the result of swapping the X and . either side of it. Choose the option that makes the least difference. If they make the same difference, prefer the leftmost edge. Now it's obvious how to make the previous one in the sequence.